# How to grep a line start with #* using grep in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a question about Grep in R: How to specify that the element start with `#*` following  (without space) by some character or number ?

```
titre_index <- grep('#\*', test)
```

> Error: '*' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'#*"

Comment: Just use `"^#\\*"` as the regex. The `^` forces it to match at the beginning of strings

Comment: Can you clarify the pattern you're looking for? see discussion below my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid the problem of figuring out how many backslashes use `[*]` to match a star.

```
grep("^#[*]", x, value = TRUE)
```

Another approach, not using any regular expressions at all, is:

```
x[ substr(x, 1, 2) == "#*" ]
```

or

```
x[ startsWith(x, "#*") ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean `\\*`. the second backslash escapes the backslash in the R string; then the combined backslashes escape the asterisk in the regular expression.

R needs to understand the string first:

```
cat('\\*')
# \*
```

The string that R understands is then passed to the regular expression engine, which needs to escape the asterisk to distinguish it from the wildcard `*`.

Regarding the complete pattern you're trying to match, I'm not sure I understand:

> start with #* following (without space) by some character or number

But I take it you want `#*` and then a letter or number, in which case this fits the bill:

```
"^#\\*[0-9a-zA-Z]"
```

Maybe slightly more legible as:

```
"^#[*][[:alnum:]]"
```

Comment: that still isn't going to just catch string starts (i.e. that fixes the error but the OP's regex may errantly catch pound+asterisk in other parts of strings)

Comment: @hrbrmstr you're right, but I'm still not sure I understand _what_ OP is trying to do... I can't parse "start with #* following (without space) by some character or number"

Comment: agreed. i was confused for a minute as well (hence the twice re-edited comment on the question)

Comment: I'm guessing OP meant followed by, not following by.